# Holomorphic section is determined by arbitrarily small neighborhood?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a connected complex manifold and $E\to X$ a holomorphic vector bundle. Suppose that $s:X\to E$ is a holomorphic section such that $s(x)=0$ for all $x$ in a non-empty open set $U\subset X$.

> Does this imply that $s$ is identically zero on $X$?

By analogy with the fact that a holomorphic function $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is determined by its values on any non-empty open set, I am convinced that the answer is yes. But I have some trouble proving this for complex manifolds.

If $X$ is compact I am able to prove it by using a finite cover of holomorphic coordinates and using the result for holomorphic functions, but that argument doesn't generalize to non-compact.

Comment: Why doesn't that argument generalize?

Comment: @MikeMiller Because we do not necessarily have a finite cover by holomorphic coordinates.

Comment: What does finiteness matter?

Comment: @MikeMiller Let $X=\bigcup_{i}U_i$ be the cover. We get that $s|_{U_i}=0$ for some $i$. Since $X$ is connected, $U_i\cap U_j\neq\emptyset$ for some $j$ and then $s|_{U_j}=0$ as well. Continuing this way we get that $s|_{U_k}$ for all $k$ because the cover is *finite*.

Comment: I don't think this uses finiteness in an essential way. Since $X$ is connected, there is a path between a point in your open set and any other point. There is a *finite chain* of open sets that cover all of this path. Use this finite chain to show the function vanishes at the other point.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks, I'll remember that trick!

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be the set of points $x \in X$ such that $s(y)=0$ forall $y$ in a non-empty open set $U \subset X$.

Obviously, $V$ is open (given such a $y$ with a corresponding open $U$, $U$ is included in $V$).

$V$ is also closed, because in any coordinate chart, it's the set of points where $f(x) = f'(x) = f''(x) = \ldots = 0$, so an intersection of closed sets.

Since $X$ is connected and $V$ is nonempty, you must then have $V=X$.

Comment: What's $f$? What's $'$?

Comment: I suppose I meant $s$, or rather the corresponding map via the chart. If $W$ is an open of $X$, a chart on $W$ is a pair $\phi : W \to W'$, $\Phi : \pi^{-1}(W) \to W' \times \Bbb C^k$  where $W'$ is an open of $\Bbb C$,  $\phi \circ \pi = \pi \circ \Phi$, and the restriction of $\pi_2 \circ \Phi$ to $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is a linear map for all $x$. Then the transcription of $s$ in that chart is the holomorphic map $f = \pi_2 \circ \Phi \circ s \circ \phi^{-1} : W' \to \Bbb C^k$. It is zero around a point iff all its derivative are $0$ at that point.